# playwright cannot find tests if run from package script

Tags: npm, playwright, npm-scripts

If i run this

//terminal

```
> npx playwright test --grep '@slow' --workers=1
```

all is ok

**BUT** if i run

//package. json

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "npx playwright test --grep '@slow' --workers=1"
```

//terminal

```
npm run test
```

I get - *Error: no tests found*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the following scripts

```json
"test": "npx playwright test --grep \"@slow\" --workers=1"
"test": "npx playwright test --grep @slow --workers=1"
```

Comment: omfg how i did i miss these single quotes in json. thank you very much!